# How to scrape app category in the new updated Google Play Store

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-play

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Shooter.ModernWarships'
req=requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("h1", class_="Fd93Bb ynrBgc xwcR9d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using classes cause they are dynamic, change your strategy and select tags or ids that are often more static.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Shooter.ModernWarships'
req=requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
soup.h1.text
```

or

```
soup.find('h1').text
```

Output

```
MODERN WARSHIPS
```